# Jasper report + Java Error loading expression class

Tags: java, jasper-reports, jasper, jaspersoft

Tengo un problema al generar reportes, aclaro que nunca use el jasper reprot.

- uso el IDE eclipse
- Java 1.7
- Descargue el complemento Jaspersoft Studio 6.20.0 [Eclipse Marketplace]
- Uso la dependencia siguiente

```
   <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sf.jasperreports/jasperreports -->
   <dependency>
       <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
       <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
       <version>6.20.0</version>
   </dependency>
```

Seguí varios tutoriales de internet, pero no logro generar el reporte, aclaro que si funciona cuando le doy Play, me previsualiza todo lo que quiero. El problema está cuando trato de generar el reporte por medio de JAVA.

```
try {
                // File reportfile = new File(("/opt/app/edo/templates/sesion1.jasper"));
                File reportfile = new File("D:\\workspace\\edomtpe\\src\\main\\resources\\report\\Paso1\\Paso0.jasper");
                Map<String, Object> parameter = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                
                /************** GENERACION DE REPORTES DE COMPROBANTES *****************/   

                Connection conn = datasource.getConnection();

                parameter.put("rucempresa", usuSession.getRucempresa());
                parameter.put("idedo", usuSession.getIdempresa());
                parameter.put("n_idencuesta", usuSession.getIdencuesta());

                System.out.println("reportfile: " + reportfile.getPath());
                System.out.println("Parameter: " + usuSession.getRucempresa() + " " + usuSession.getIdempresa() + " "
                        + usuSession.getIdencuesta());
                System.out.println("conn: " + conn);

                byte[] bytes = JasperRunManager.runReportToPdf(reportfile.getPath(), parameter);
                response.setContentType("application/pdf");
                response.setContentLength(bytes.length);
                ServletOutputStream outputstream = response.getOutputStream();
                outputstream.write(bytes, 0, bytes.length);

                outputstream.flush();
                outputstream.close();
                conn.close();
            }
```

En un inicio pensé que era el reporte por qué le enviaba parámetros para la consulta interna SQL, así que decidí crear un reporte en blanco con un texto static, pero aun así no me genera el reporte. La duda que tengo es la ruta del archivo, la coloque así porque antes me daba **file no found**. La ruta es "src/main/resources/report/Paso1/Paso0.jasper". La verdad no se que más hacer, tengo reportes viejos que si funcionan, y necesito actualizarlos, cuando los modifico y compiló dejan de funcionar, asumo que es algo de compatibilidad. Los estaré leyendo y buscando la solución.

```
15:43:46 [default task-5] stderr - net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Error loading expression class : Paso0_1663348362569_762760

15:43:46 [default task-5] stderr -  at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JRAbstractJavaCompiler.loadEvaluator(JRAbstractJavaCompiler.java:116)

15:43:46 [default task-5] stderr -  at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JRAbstractCompiler.loadEvaluator(JRAbstractCompiler.java:340)

15:43:46 [default task-5] stderr -  at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager.getEvaluator(JasperCompileManager.java:378)

15:43:46 [default task-5] stderr -  at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillDataset.createCalculator(JRFillDataset.java:462)

15:43:46 [default task-5] stderr -  at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.BaseReportFiller.<init>(BaseReportFiller.java:151)

15:43:46 [default task-5] stderr -  at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.<init>(JRBaseFiller.java:229)

15:43:46 [default task-5] stderr -  at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.<init>(JRVerticalFiller.java:74)

15:43:46 [default task-5] stderr -  at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.<init>(JRVerticalFiller.java:62)

15:43:46 [default task-5] stderr -  at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.createBandReportFiller(JRFiller.java:187)

15:43:46 [default task-5] stderr -  at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.createReportFiller(JRFiller.java:202)

15:43:46 [default task-5] stderr -  at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.fill(JRFiller.java:150)

15:43:46 [default task-5] stderr -  at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fill(JasperFillManager.java:311)

15:43:46 [default task-5] stderr -  at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperRunManager.runToPdf(JasperRunManager.java:278)

15:43:46 [default task-5] stderr -  at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperRunManager.runReportToPdf(JasperRunManager.java:767)

15:43:46 [default task-5] stderr -  at pe.gob.trabajo.controller.encuestaController.sesionu(encuestaController.java:896)

15:43:46 [default task-5] stderr -  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

15:43:46 [default task-5] stderr -  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)

15:43:46 [default task-5] stderr -  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)

15:43:46 [default task-5] stderr -  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)

15:43:46 [default task-5] stderr -  at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:219)

15:43:46 [default task-5] stderr -  at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)

15:43:46 [default task-5] stderr -  at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)

15:43:46 [default task-5] stderr -  at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:745)

15:43:46 [default task-5] stderr -  at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:686)

15:43:46 [default task-5] stderr -  at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)

15:43:46 [default task-5] stderr -  at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)

15:43:46 [default task-5] stderr -  at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)

15:43:46 [default task-5] stderr -  at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)

15:43:46 [default task-5] stderr -  at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:827)

15:43:46 [default task-5] stderr -  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)

15:43:46 [default task-5] stderr -  at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)

15:43:46 [default task-5] stderr -  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)

15:43:46 [default task-5] stderr -  at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:74)

15:43:46 [default task-5] stderr -  at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)

15:43:46 [default task-5] stderr -  at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletChain$1.handleRequest(ServletChain.java:67)

15:43:46 [default task-5] stderr -  at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)

15:43:46 [default task-5] stderr -  at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)

15:43:46 [default task-5] stderr -  at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)

15:43:46 [default task-5] stderr -  at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)

15:43:46 [default task-5] stderr -  at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)

15:43:46 [default task-5] stderr -  at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)

15:43:46 [default task-5] stderr -  at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)

15:43:46 [default task-5] stderr -  at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)

15:43:46 [default task-5] stderr -  at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)

15:43:46 [default task-5] stderr -  at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)

15:43:46 [default task-5] stderr -  at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)

15:43:46 [default task-5] stderr -  at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)

15:43:46 [default task-5] stderr -  at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)

15:43:46 [default task-5] stderr -  at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)

15:43:46 [default task-5] stderr -  at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)

15:43:46 [default task-5] stderr -  at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.GlobalRequestControllerHandler.handleRequest(GlobalRequestControllerHandler.java:68)

15:43:46 [default task-5] stderr -  at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)

15:43:46 [default task-5] stderr -  at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:292)

15:43:46 [default task-5] stderr -  at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)

15:43:46 [default task-5] stderr -  at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:138)

15:43:46 [default task-5] stderr -  at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:135)

15:43:46 [default task-5] stderr -  at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)

15:43:46 [default task-5] stderr -  at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)

15:43:46 [default task-5] stderr -  at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105)

15:43:46 [default task-5] stderr -  at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1526)

15:43:46 [default task-5] stderr -  at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1526)

15:43:46 [default task-5] stderr -  at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1526)

15:43:46 [default task-5] stderr -  at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1526)

15:43:46 [default task-5] stderr -  at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:272)

15:43:46 [default task-5] stderr -  at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)

15:43:46 [default task-5] stderr -  at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:104)

15:43:46 [default task-5] stderr -  at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:360)

15:43:46 [default task-5] stderr -  at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:830)

15:43:46 [default task-5] stderr -  at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)

15:43:46 [default task-5] stderr -  at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1985)

15:43:46 [default task-5] stderr -  at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1487)

15:43:46 [default task-5] stderr -  at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1378)

15:43:46 [default task-5] stderr -  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

15:43:46 [default task-5] stderr - Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: net.sf.jasperreports.compilers.ReportExpressionEvaluationData cannot be cast to [B

15:43:46 [default task-5] stderr -  at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JRAbstractJavaCompiler.loadEvaluator(JRAbstractJavaCompiler.java:102)

15:43:46 [default task-5] stderr -  ... 72 more
```

Comment: Lo único que se me ocurre es que exista algún problema con el JDK o JRE de tu máquina y el IDE, que no sean las mismas.  Te serviría ver esto: https://community.oracle.com/tech/developers/discussion/1240881/problem-with-jasperreport

Comment: El 4to parámetro de `runReportToPdf()` es la conexión ¿la necesita tu reporte?. En lugar de usar la ruta prueba con un `InputStream` como 1er parámetro.

Comment: El reporte con nombre paso0 no lo necesitas, pero los otros que construi si lo necesita.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encontré la solución a esto, al descargar el complemento del marketplace este me instalo el jasperreport 6.20.0, entonces cuando modifique los reportes los guardaba en la versión actual. En la opción Compatibility conguration cambié para guardar en la versión 6.0.0, pero aun así no funcionaba, entonces agregué el JAR (6.0.0) a en Managment jasperreport version, con ello pude guardar los reportes en la versión 6.0.0 y funciono perfectamente.

Answer (score 1):

quizás te sirva mi caso.
Por muchos años usé ireport 4 con netbeans en un proyecto de escritorio y bibliotecas jasperreports-4.0.1, commons-collections-2.1.1 etc etc, compatibles entre ellas.
Justo hoy inicié una prueba para usar jasperstudio 6.20 y actualizar paulatinamente esos reportes que han estado sin cambios durante años.
Para esto, mis reportes están dentro del proyecto tal como tú los tienes, la cosa es que me salió un error igual que no podía cargar.
En mi proyecto, quité todas esas bibliotecas viejas y puse commons-collections4-4.4, jasperreports-fonts-6.20.0 y jasperreports-6.20.0.
Funcionó al 100%, y puedo comentar 1) no funciona teniendo bibliotecas viejas y nuevas 2)las bibliotecas nuevas ejecutan tanto reportes nuevos o tranformados a jasperstudio, así como los reportes echos con ireport viejo.

Favor de responder si te funcionó o no, en cualquier caso.
Ya que casi no tengo experiencia con web.

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).